# LDAP changed account Full Name is not displaying in gerrit web page

Tags: gerrit

I am using Gerrit 2.8.5 with LDAP Authentication. Now we have set the Full Name for the gerrit service account in Windows and Linux. This service account is our Gerrit admin and earlier it was not having Full Name. But still Gerrit is not displaying the Full Name in WebUI for this service account.

It is also not allowing me to set the full name using gerrit set-account command. Restarting Gerrit service will solve the problem? What about editing gerrit accounts table directly in the database?

Comment: Well, you already suggest a restart.. This also flushes the caches, so should help.

Comment: Have you tried logging out? Sometime changes are not effective until you log and log in again

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `ldap.accountFullName` in the [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#ldap).

In our case we had to adjust it since the default setting in `gerrit.config` did not fit our need:

```
[ldap]
    ...
    accountFullName = cn
    ...
```

Please also be aware that gerrit will never be able to update LDAP information since they should be managed at a central area.

And yes, don't forget to restart the service.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This solved my issue but I used "accountFullName = displayName" instead of cn.